How remove html tag by id from pagination pages (Woo)
Is there a way to remove a block of text by id from only pagination pages (/?product-page=1)?
Using WordPress 6.5.2 + Woocommerce 8.8.2
Description problem:
On the post page https://site.ru/mypost/ in the content part there are:

Shortcode [products limit=”6″ pagination=”true”], which displays products broken down into paginated pages.

A block of text in <div id="description-art"></div>.


If you go to the pagination page https://site.ru/mypost/?product-page=2, the block with text in
<div id="description-art"></div> will be duplicated.
It would be correct for a block with text to appear only on the main page, and on pages with pagination this block would disappear.
For example,
Here a block of text is displayed – https://site.ru/mypost/
here block is not displayed https://site.ru/mypost/?product-page=1
I would appreciate your help. The search for working solutions on stackoverflow did not yield results.
The problem is relevant for many who use pagination and text, which on the one hand informs visitors. On the other hand, it helps the search engine rank the site better.
Solving the problem will help you avoid duplicating the same
content on all pagination pages. Especially if there are a lot of them.
It is necessary that the HTML tag with a certain id be removed from all pagination pages, but remain on the main (canonical) page - WordPress 6.5.2 + Woocommerce 8.8.2
